# Does iAd work with Cordova iOS platform?

Tags: ios, iphone, iad, cordova-3

I'm working with cordova for ios platform.now, want to integrate IAd into my app.i m following this [**LINK**](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-iad)
but, somehow CDViAd plugin is not called.can anyone suggest, where should I made mistake?

I've done this steps:

1. Added CDViAd.h and CDViAd.m fiel into plugin folder.
2. Added iAd and adsupport frameworks.
3. Copied iAd.js into www folder.
4. Added this code into the config.xml file

   > ```
   > <feature name="iAd">
   >     <param name="ios-package" value="CDViAd" />
   > </feature>
   > ```
5. Copied index.html file from the link.

Comment: Could be some files inside `platform/ios/` hasn't been updated yet. Try to run `cordova plugin add https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-iad`

Answer (score 0):

You Weak Linked the iAd Framework as per the README?

I found another step to do here is , in Cordova.plist or PhoneGap.plist , under the Plugins section, add an identical key and value of the plugin.